# Meaning of "cepeo"

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, cibus

What does *cepeo* mean?

According to Google Translate, this means "onions".

Are there any connotations, other words that carry the same meaning, or anything else specifically related to it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I have checked a couple of printed and online dictionaries and found no trace of *cepeo*, but Google Translate does indeed translate it to onions. There are similar words meaning "onion", for example *cepa*, *cepe*, and *caepe*. Have you seen *cepeo* in other places? It seems wrong to me, but I could be mistaken. Context (where you found the word originally or where you want to use it) will help answering your question.

Comment: The Latin word for onion is cepa or caepa (feminine) or else cepe or caepe (neuter). Google translate is rubbish.

Comment: A list of onion words, mostly from Whitaker's compilation of sources: http://latin-english.com/english/onion/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two data points:

- There are no results on [The Latin Library for cepeo](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Awww.thelatinlibrary.com%20cepeo).
- There are no results on [The Perseus Project for cepeo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?target=la&all_words=cepeo&phrase=&any_words=&exclude_words=&documents=).